# Pasting text into Windows 7, WordPad

Tags: windows-7, wordpad

Everytime I paste text into WordPad, from pretty much any source, extra lines are inserted. Such as I want to paste -

```
  This is line 1.
  This is line 2.
  This is line 3.
```

Becomes -

```
  This is line 1.


  This is line 2.


  This is line 3.
```

Anybody know how to stop this from happening?
Thanks!

Comment: Paste text from what source?

Comment: It seems to have the issue from any source. Even Notepad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clicking the paragraph button (to the right of the justification options) and then unchecking "Add 10pt space after paragraphs". Click "OK" and try again.